# How can the right object type be chosen, when using operator overloading in inherited classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I am currently writing on a project in Python 3, which is quite huge and will consist of multiple classes. As these files are quite huge I came up with a simpler problem, depicted below.

## Base Class

I have a base class called `Vector()` with multiple methods and performing operator overloading.

```
class Vector():
 def __init__(self, vector):
  self.vector=vector
  self.length=len(vector)

 ## general methods
 def output(self):
  return (str(self.__class__.__name__)+" "+str(self.vector)+" "+str(self.compute()))

 ## class specific method
 def compute(self):
  return self.vector[0]  #returns the length spanned by 1-dimensional vector.

 ## operator overloading
 def __add__(self, summand):
  d=[]
  for i in range(self.length):
   d.append(self.vector[i]+summand.vector[i])
  return Vector(d)
  
a=Vector([1])
b=Vector([2])
c=a+b
print(a.output())
print(b.output())
print(c.output())
```

The outcome is as expected:

```
Vector [1] 1
Vector [2] 2
Vector [3] 3
```

We have 3 objects `a`,`b` and `c`, and `c` is the sum of `a` and `b`.

## Derived Class

However, the projects needs to have inherited subclasses to deal with different data and datasources, similar to this:

```
class Vector2(Vector):
 def __init__(self, vector):
  super().__init__(vector)

 ## class specific method, all other stuff inherited
 def compute(self):
  return self.vector[0]*self.vector[1]  #returns the area spanned by 2-dimensional vector.

d=Vector2([1,2])
e=Vector2([4,3])
f=e+d
print(d.output())
print(e.output())
print(f.output())
```

The output is the following:

```
Vector2 [1, 2] 2
Vector2 [4, 3] 12
Vector [5, 5] 5  ## <= should be 25
```

My problem now is, that `d` and `e` are correctly instanciated as `Vector2()` objects and everything works fine with them, but the resulting `f` is **only** a `Vector()` object, having the *wrong* `f.compute()` result. (In fact it is the right result, but the wrong object type.)

## Potential Solutions

I came up with the following solutions:

1. Copy/Pasting all the operator overloading into the derived classes, instanciating the right class each time. This is in my opinion against the rules of code reusability in object oriented programming. And tedious work as already dozens of operator overloading methods exist in each class and a hand full of classes already exist. Code maintenance would be awful. **==> DISCARDED**
2. Adjust the operator overloading methods similar to that:

```
class Vector():
 # ... 
 ## operator overloading extended version 
 def __add__(self, summand):
  d=[]
  for i in range(self.length):
   d.append(self.vector[i]+summand.vector[i])
  if self.__class__.__name__=="Vector2":
   return Vector2(d)
  else:
   return Vector(d)
```

The result

```
Vector2 [1, 2] 2
Vector2 [4, 3] 12
Vector2 [5, 5] 25
```

is ok now, but it would require to update all the base class's operator overloading methods, each time a new derived class is added to the project (`Vector3()`,`Vector4()`, `FancyVector()`, ...). Over time this might well be a few dozen. **==> UNHAPPY with that**

## Final Question

Is there a way to dynamically instanciate objects in the base class, to return the correct object type from operator overloading, when the returned object type is a descendent of that base class?

In other words: Can Python detect the object type of inherited operator overloading methods and return the correct derived object type?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some sort of bi-directional inheritance...seems like an odd way to try solve this problem. What you seem to want is a *overloaded function* that takes a list of length `n` and returns a `Vec2`, `Vec3`, etc as appropriate for the given length `n`. If the problem seems to have too much friction for the tool you've chosen (inheritance in this case) pick a different tool.

Comment: @ Jared Smith I like the term *bi-directional inheritance*, as it quite describes the problem I encounter. Just, that the real problem is not only to pick the right object type from the length `n`. But thank you for the hint: That was problem solution #3, that I did not mention in my post, because it would lead to rethink the whole architecture of that project. *uggh*

Comment: Will the left hand side of your operator always determine the result type? And will all your vector subclasses *ever* be constructile with a single list argument? If that is the case, you can just return `type(self)(new_data)`

Comment: See my answer, hopefully that shows you at least a better API for this thing even if there's some tedium in typing out all the overloads.

Comment: Please use 4-space indentation as recommended by PEP-8. It's hard to see the structure with only one space of indentation.

Comment: @ Wombatz Currently it is designed to perform this way, if `left-hand type == right-hand  type`, then return `type`, else fall-back to `base type`. And the number of arguments in `__init__` is currently static and has always the same length. However, I cannot exclude that someday this might change, but I will tackle that, when I arrive there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've hard coded the return type when instead you could use the type of `self` which will be derived class.

```
class Vector():
    def __init__(self, vector):
        self.vector = vector
        self.length = len(vector)
    
    ## general methods
    def output(self):
        return (str(self.__class__.__name__)+" "+str(self.vector)+" "+str(self.compute()))

    ## class specific method
    def compute(self):
        return self.vector[0]  #returns the length spanned by 1-dimensional vector.

    ## operator overloading
    def __add__(self, summand):
        d=[]
        for i in range(self.length):
            d.append(self.vector[i]+summand.vector[i])
        return type(self)(d)

a=Vector([1])
b=Vector([2])
c=a+b
print(a.output())
print(b.output())
print(c.output())


print("=========================")

class Vector2(Vector):
    # if it doesn't do anything, let python find its super init
    #def __init__(self, vector):
    #    super().__init__(vector)

    ## class specific method, all other stuff inherited
    def compute(self):
        return self.vector[0]*self.vector[1]  #returns the area spanned by 2-dimensional vector.

d=Vector2([1,2])
e=Vector2([4,3])
f=e+d
print(d.output())
print(e.output())
print(f.output())
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on OP's comment that the resulting type of the `__add__` method should be the same as the operand types if they are identical and otherwise the base class, we can implement `__add__` according to those rules:

```py
class Vector:
    ...

    def __add__(self, other: 'Vector') -> 'Vector':
        if type(self) is type(other):
            result_type = type(self)
        else:
            result_type = Vector

        summed_data = ...  # calculate the sum here
        return result_type(summed_data)
```

Note: for this to work, all future `__init__` methods must accept a single argument. If this is not possible, we can introduce a helper method that creates a copy of the vector with new data:

```py
class Vector:
    ...

    def _copy_with_data(self, new_data: Sequence[int]) -> typing.Self:
        return type(self)(new_data)

    def __add__(self, other: 'Vector') -> 'Vector':
        summed_vector = ...  # calculate the sum here

        if type(self) is type(other):
            return self._copy_with_data(summed_vector)
        return Vector(summed_vector)
```

If a subclass now has a different `__init__`-signature, it must override the `_copy_with_data` method:

```py
# this subclass needs another constructor argument: construction is incompatible
class ColoredVector(Vector):
    def __init__(self, vector: Sequence[int], color: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(vector)
        self.color = color

    def _copy_with_data(self, new_data: Sequence[int]) -> Self:
        # copy self and keep color
        return type(self)(new_data, self.color)
```

If this simple logic is not enough, you have to override `__add__`.

**Mypy note**: It does not seem to be possible to type hint this logic more accurately than `'Vector'`

Answer (score 1):

If you want maximum type safety here what you want is an overloaded function that returns the correct type of Vec object based on the *length of the argument*, and to disambiguate it would be ideal to use a fixed length Tuple rather than a variable length list:

```
from typing import overload, Tuple, Union

class Vec1:
    def __init__(self, vector: Tuple[int]):
        self.vector=vector
        self.length=1

    ## general methods
    def output(self):
        return (str(self.__class__.__name__)+" "+str(self.vector)+" "+str(self.compute()))

    ## class specific method
    def compute(self):
        return self.vector[0]  #returns the length spanned by 1-dimensional vector.

    ## operator overloading
    def __add__(self, summand):
        d=[]
        for i in range(self.length):
            d.append(self.vector[i]+summand.vector[i])
        return Vector(d)

class Vec2(Vec1):
    def __init__(self, vector: Tuple[int, int]):
        self.vector=vector
        self.length=2

    def compute(self):
        return self.vector[0]*self.vector[1]

@overload
def Vector(ns: Tuple[int]) -> Vec1:
    ...

@overload
def Vector(ns: Tuple[int, int]) -> Vec2:
    ...

def Vector(ns: Union[Tuple[int], Tuple[int, int]]) -> Union[Vec1, Vec2]:
    length = len(ns)
    if length == 1:
        return Vec1(ns)
    elif length == 2:
        return Vec2(ns)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Cannot construct vector of dimension {}".format(length))

foo = Vector((1,))   // Vec1
bar = Vector((3, 4)) // Vec2
print(foo.output())  // prints 1
print(bar.output())  // prints 12
```

If the problem seems to have too much friction for the tool you've chosen (inheritance in this case) pick a different tool.

You can give up some safety to gain flexibility and concision (e.g. you wouldn't have to define a different `__init__` on each class), if you take a variable length list and switch on the list you'll get back the right *value* at runtime but static checkers like pyright and mypy won't be able to discriminate the union of the return type.

Note that you *will* **always** need to define the operator overloading for the derived classes, since it needs to perform a different computation depending on the dimensionality.

Comment: @ Jared Smith At a first glance this looks neat and seems to be able to ease the problem. I will have to rethink this... Thanks a lot

Comment: This is essentially saying to use the Factory pattern to create the appropriate return type. But it only works if you can determine the proper type based on the arguments to the factory function, and it doesn't generalize very well.

Comment: @Barmar I mean that's fair, but if we're just talking about vectors it's a lot cleaner than messing around with trying to do a bunch of duck typing in every method (if somewhat verbose). IDK they pay me to write Typescript these days, I may have picked up an accent so to speak over the last couple of years :)